# Should Swing games only have a drawing component?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing

I've been using a `JPanel` and overriding `paintComponent()` in order to perform my drawing in Swing games. I'm now trying to add an inventory, which will contain different items the player can drag around and move to different slots in his "backpack" on the screen. Should Swing games only draw on a single `JPanel` or other component (example: draw images of item at mouse location) or can you add `JButton`s whose icons are pictures of the items?

Should the game only have the one drawing component, or can you include more?

Comment: There is no problem drawing on several components. And of course you can also add Swing components like `JButton` or any others that would fit to your design .

Comment: The question comes down to several things - do you want Swing controlling the painting process or not and how complex the game is. If you're comfortable for Swing to do all the painting for you, then you shouldn't have any issues. If you want to take control of the painting process (`BufferedStrategy`), then you may run into issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Principally, you can have any number of components that you want to have. Swing – as any other sufficently elaborate library such as SWT for Java or Qt and WxWidgets for C++ – is intelligent enough to draw to the screen only what actually really is necessary.

As long as you do not run into performance issues, there is no problem with that. If this actually happens, you might first want to look at your own paintComponent implementation as this is the most probable location where you lose efficiency.